# using php code to create custom form to point[map] a subdomain to domain

Tags: domain-mapping

I am in the process of creating a web application where user can create their own website with subdomain. I need to create a form where user can enter their registered domain a record or cname so that subdomain is pointed to the registered main domain.

To make my question simple, while looking for dns record when they search with maindomain.com it should look into mysubdomain.newdomain.com

I'm in need of a php script that will do this. Please share any ideas.